# Do I implement my own Dispose() or do I use Finalize() for .NET 3.5 RNGCryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, .net

Looks like they made a mistake on the example for .NET 3.5 so I'm using .NET 3.5 but the code example is for .NET 4 and above.  (because Dispose() method not available in .NET 3.6)

Do I have implement my own Dispose() or do i use Finalize() ?  Or should I follow the example for .NET 2.0 instead?

Here is the example on MSDN that shows up when you select .NET 3.5

```
//The following sample uses the Cryptography class to simulate the roll of a dice. 

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class RNGCSP
{
private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
// Main method. 
public static void Main()
{
    const int totalRolls = 25000;
    int[] results = new int[6];

    // Roll the dice 25000 times and display 
    // the results to the console. 
    for (int x = 0; x < totalRolls; x++)
    {
        byte roll = RollDice((byte)results.Length);
        results[roll - 1]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; ++i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} ({2:p1})", i + 1, results[i], (double)results[i] / (double)totalRolls);
    }
    rngCsp.Dispose();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// This method simulates a roll of the dice. The input parameter is the 
// number of sides of the dice. 

public static byte RollDice(byte numberSides)
{
    if (numberSides <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numberSides");

    // Create a byte array to hold the random value.
    byte[] randomNumber = new byte[1];
    do
    {
        // Fill the array with a random value.
        rngCsp.GetBytes(randomNumber);
    }
    while (!IsFairRoll(randomNumber[0], numberSides));
    // Return the random number mod the number 
    // of sides.  The possible values are zero- 
    // based, so we add one. 
    return (byte)((randomNumber[0] % numberSides) + 1);
}

private static bool IsFairRoll(byte roll, byte numSides)
{
    // There are MaxValue / numSides full sets of numbers that can come up 
    // in a single byte.  For instance, if we have a 6 sided die, there are 
    // 42 full sets of 1-6 that come up.  The 43rd set is incomplete. 
    int fullSetsOfValues = Byte.MaxValue / numSides;

    // If the roll is within this range of fair values, then we let it continue. 
    // In the 6 sided die case, a roll between 0 and 251 is allowed.  (We use 
    // < rather than <= since the = portion allows through an extra 0 value). 
    // 252 through 255 would provide an extra 0, 1, 2, 3 so they are not fair 
    // to use. 
    return roll < numSides * fullSetsOfValues;
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

Your instance is static and should remain that way. There is no reason to throw it away or regenerate it. You should just have one and extract bytes from it during all of your applications lifetime. So don't ever dispose or finalize it. This is so because the uniformity of the generator and strength can guarantee that there really is no reason to recycle or regenerate a cryptographic *RNG*.

At a programs exit all disposable resources are already be taken care of.